# Strange Behavior with QTCPSocket readAll() function

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am currently implementing a c++ application in VS2010 that reads data from a TCP socket and populates a database.
For reading data from the TCP socket I used the QT readAll() function.

QByteArray text = socket.readAll();

My application constantly populates the database so, I need to read data every 5 seconds approximately, 
however the readAll() function reads nothing after the first execution (the first time everything is fine). The size of text is 0, while I was expecting it to be 75.

I checked the socket status and it is connected.
I also checked for errors and nothing seems to be the problem.
The data are being transmitted from the server constantly (I checked it with wireshark)

How can I resolve this strange behaviour? 
One thing that I suspect is the while loop that is in, but I cannot think of any workarounds

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataCollectionService.h"

int main(int argv, char **args){

QCoreApplication app(argv, args);       

DataCollectionService *newCollection = new DataCollectionService(&app);

QObject::connect(newCollection, SIGNAL(finished()), &app, SLOT(quit()));    

return(app.exec());
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma once

#ifndef DATACOLLECTION_H
#define DATACOLLECTION_H

#include "TCPClient.h"
#include "MySqlConnection.h"
#include "QtGui\qapplication.h"
#include "QtCore\qobject.h"
#include "QtCore\qtimer.h"

class DataCollectionService: public QObject{

Q_OBJECT

public:
DataCollectionService(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent){

    newClient.InitializeTCPConnection();

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(run()));
    timer->start(1000); 
}   

private:
MySqlConnection newConnection;  
TCPClient newClient;    

private slots:
    void run();

signals:
    void finished();

};
#endif


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DataCollectionService::run(){

newClient.UpdateMeasurements();                         

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void TCPClient::InitializeTCPConnection(){

socket.connectToHost("160.40.1.188", 2078, QIODevice::ReadWrite); ///remote host and port

if(socket.waitForConnected()){

    if(!socket.waitForReadyRead()){
        transmissionError = true;
    }
}

else{
    transmissionError = true;
}       
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void TCPClient::UpdateMeasurements(){

transmissionError = false;

QByteArray text = socket.readAll(); ///////this gets data only once!!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QT applications are designed to work with events looping, which take place at `QApplication :: exec()`. You can't just run your loop, you need to use QT's mechanisms.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try it but I am pretty sure that this is the problem

Comment: No luck, even if I followed the instructions, I updated the code at the question, and now I am using qt mechanisms. I still cant understand the behavior. It just receives data once!

Answer (score -1):

Finally solved it.

It needed to add

qApp->processEvents();

inside the run() function

everything works fine now